# Iterator does not work in a simple loop

Tags: ruby, loops, iterator

Very annoying mistake, but I'm still learning, so please be helpful.
I read a file, make a table and iterate it. Was wondering why my iteration incrementation does not work in this type of loop.

```
nrOfWordsInOneLine_array = Array.new { Hash.new }

iterator = 0
nrOfWordsInOneLine_array.each_with_index do |i, j|
    iterator =+ 1
    puts "Word in line #{j+1} #{iterator} is: #{i.length} and the longest one is #{i.max_by(&:length)} with #{i.max_by(&:length).length} letters"
end
```

output:

```
Word in line 1 1 is: 8 and the longest one is First with 5 letters
Word in line 2 1 is: 6 and the longest one is Second with 6 letters
Word in line 3 1 is: 4 and the longest one is Fourth with 6 letters
Word in line 4 1 is: 2 and the longest one is Fifth with 5 letters
```

Comment: Change the operator in iterator, the way you are doing is setting the number 1 to the iterator variable, look at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm $i +=1 and not $i =+ 1

Comment: Why do you need this `iterator` at all, as it literally is an exact value provided by `j` already?

Comment: Two general comments: 1) one Ruby convention is to use "snake case" for names of variables and methods (`nr_of_words_in_one_line_array`); 2) `Hash.new` (without an argument or block) is equivalent to the more commonly-used `{}`. Similarly, you can write `[]` in place of `Array.new`.

Comment: mudasobwa: It has no better function that me lerning, playing, checking if it works and have double check to find my understanding of the new language and what I'm still missing.

Comment: Cary S.: if you refere to sth like this: nrOfWordsInOneLine_array = [] {} it will produce :  syntax error, unexpected { arg, expecting keyword_end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`iterator =+ 1` You have the `+` and `=` around the wrong way.

You want `iterator += 1`, right now you are setting `iterator` to `+1` which is `1`.